# apt-get install python3-venv is not working

Tags: python, python-venv

I am using a chromebook, using Debian. I need to run the terminal command `python -m venv env`, but when I use it, I get the errors

```
The virtual environment was not created successfully because ensurepip is not
available.  On Debian/Ubuntu systems, you need to install the python3-venv
package using the following command.

    apt-get install python3-venv

You may need to use sudo with that command.  After installing the python3-venv
package, recreate your virtual environment.

Failing command: ['/home/jacob/env/bin/python3', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']
```

so I run `apt-get install python3-venv`

but get the errors

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
```

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 3):

As it says,

- "You may need to use sudo with that command."
- "are you root?"

Do `sudo apt-get install python3-venv` to run the `apt-get` command as root.

After that, you should not need to run other commands as root (or using `sudo`) *unless* there are some system-level library dependencies for your Python dependencies. (You shouldn't need to `apt-get install` any other `python3` packages.)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken and you are looking for the Windows version of this command try:   python3 -m venv /path/to/new/virtual/environment

Answer (score 2):

It is:

```sh
sudo apt-get install python3-venv
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a permission issue.

Try:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-venv
```

Comment: It doesn't give me python3.9 though :(

Answer (score 1):

To install any package using `apt` you must be a root user to install and remove any package. Once the installation is done then any user can use that package if you have allowed them to access it (By default whenever root install a package other users gets permission to run it)

So to solve this problem try:

```sh
sudo apt-get install python3-venv
```

or

```sh
sudo su
apt-get install python3-venv
```

By using the `sudo su` you become the root user. So when you are a root user you don't have to append the `sudo` before your command.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a specific version.

I used this and solved my problem for python3.10:

```
 $ sudo apt-get install python3.10-venv
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Just do:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend
```

and try again

Answer (score -2):

If someone is facing with this issue, just run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install python3.10-venv
```

Where python3.10-venv stands for python3.10 in this example